# asp.net identity table not updating after trigger

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, t-sql, asp.net-identity

I have a seemingly odd occurrence happening and I'm not sure why. I'm working on a site using asp.net identity. I have added several columns to the AspNetUsers table by a SQL script. I have also added a trigger script to update these new columns that runs after a new user is created (inserted). This is working as expected. But later when I try to update any of the columns with a stored procedure that were populated by the trigger, they values do not update. No error message, but the old values remain. However when I deleted the trigger and ran the stored procedure, the values are updated. I'm not sure if there is an error in my trigger script or if this is just a quirky Entity framework thing?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TRG_InsertAspNetUsers') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER TRG_InsertAspNetUsers
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_InsertAspNetUsers
ON [Database].[dbo].AspNetUsers
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
UPDATE anu
SET Avatar = 'default_avatar.png',
    ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
    CreateDate = GETDATE(),
    IsActive = 1
FROM AspNetUsers anu
INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Id = anu.Id  
END
GO
```

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I think the problem is with the trigger. After the initial insert, whenever I attempt to update the 'Avatar', 'ModifiedDate', 'CreateDate' or 'IsActive' columns, the values always end up being those specified in the trigger. So it seems like my trigger is taking effect whenever the table row is modified and not just when a new row is inserted.

Comment: Turns out it was a poorly written trigger script. Changed the line 'AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS' to 'AFTER INSERT AS' and it's now working as intended.